# How to create API on Azure App Service with email, Facebook and Google login options?

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps

I saw on Azure Portal that we can enable authentication using Facebook, Google, Twitter and Microsoft Authentication Providers, but there is no option to allow users to use their email and chosen passwords.

How can I allow these 3 options (remembering that the user can link the chosen email and password to a Facebook account for instance)?